# How can I stop my footer from extending just a few pixels? I have a border around my HTML

Tags: html, css

please see the following:

[image]

As you can see, the footer sticks out by a few pixels and ruins the border I have.

I have applied the following css:

```
    html:before, html:before {
        content: "";
        position: fixed;
        background: #124381;
        left: 0;
        right: 0;
        height: 10px;
    }

    html:before {
        top: 0;
    }
    html:after {
        bottom: 0;
    }
    html   {
        border-left: 10px solid #124381;
        border-right: 10px solid #124381;  
    }

.footer {
    padding-top: 5px;
    background-color:#fff;
    position:fixed;
    bottom:0px;
    left:0px;
    right:0px;
    height:35px;
    margin-left: 10px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    text-align: center;
    border-top: 1px solid #e5e5e5;
  }
```

My footer only contains the following:

```
<div class="footer">
  <div class="container">
    <p>
      <a href="http://www.twitter.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
      <a href="http://www.instagram.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-instagram"></i></a>
      <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official"></i></a>
    </p>
  </div>
</div>
```

I really want to get rid of the jutting out footer but cannot figure out how.

Thanks

Comment: why don't you just use margin-right ?

Comment: hi.  can you please explain?  do you mean remove the margin-left entirely?

Comment: no I mean margin-right 12px for example

Comment: also the margin is fine until I add the font awesome to it.  after i add any content to the footer, it increases by a few pixels out the side

Comment: oh ok.  wow lol i guess that will solve problem.  however do you know why it would jut out just a little bit?

Comment: why is html position fixed?

Comment: I wanted it to be at the bottom of the browser view, so upon scroll it would stay the bottom of the view.